# Getting error while using express framework when responding inside setInterval()

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating simple application to send a simple message hello when the user requests get request of home page.

```
app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    setInterval(function(){
        res.status(200);
        res.send("hello");
    },5000)
})
```

The Idea is to send response after 5 seconds.
The compiler is throwing error after sending response .
The error is as follows

node:_http_outgoing:663
throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:663:11)
at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\prudh\OneDrive\Documents\projects\whatsapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\prudh\OneDrive\Documents\projects\whatsapp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\prudh\OneDrive\Documents\projects\whatsapp\index.js:40:13)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7) {
code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

Why am I facing this error message.

This is the basic code block so I have not tried anything.

Answer (score 1):

[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) runs function repeatedly, so you see this error when it tries to run function second time, because response is already sent to client. Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) instead to delay function:

```
app.get("/",(req,res) =>
    setTimeout(() => res.status(200).send("hello"), 5000)
)
```